# How to use FluentValidation.AspNetCore and FluentValidation.MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

How to use FluentValidation.AspNetCore and FluentValidation.MVC6 to validate Entities in AspNetCore , can anyone give me an example ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is working for me:

project.json add:

```json
"FluentValidation.AspNetCore": "6.4.0-beta3"
```

startup.cs

```cs
services
.AddMvc()
.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

Validation:

```cs
public class Foo
{
     public string Bar {get; set;}
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo> 
{
    public FooValidator()
    { 
        RuleFor(x => x.Bar).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Error Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works on .net core mvc project but only when posting it will not do any client side validation like it did in prior versions of MVC.  I know this is not done yet according to github but am wondering if anyone has a work around for the client side stuff?

Comment: This works but
When a validation error occurs I get from the API the object created by FluentValidation. I need to create my custom return object and copy into it the errors.
Ideas?
I can't do it with exception filters and the way that is explained for .net MVC (non-core) does not work in core (or i'm doing it wrong).

Comment: I would like to add a detail to the answer. Adding FluentValidation in the pipeline will only ensure that the ModelState is updated. It will not automatically return HTTP 400 when invalid. The most basic solution is to do the following in your controller actions:

            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

For less repetitive code, you can add an attribute on your controller. See ValidateModelAttribute here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add nuget **Install-Package FluentValidation.AspNetCore**

you can have an action filter which will handle validation:

```
public class ValidatorActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(filterContext.ModelState);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Startup.ConfigureServices looks like this to add auto validation and add FluentValidation:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {
            opt.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidatorActionFilter));
        }).AddFluentValidation(fvc => 
   fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
```

If you need to read another assembly, name one of its **classes** instead of **startUp**

Now you can add a validation to ensure:

```
public class CreateCustomer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class CreateCustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateCustomer>
{
    public CreateCustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull().WithMessage(Resource.Validaton.FirstNameRequired);
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull().WithMessage(Resource.Validaton.LastNameRequired);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).Matches(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z").WithMessage(Resource.Validaton.EmailFormat);
    }
}
```